# Python string conversion to integer

Tags: python, integer, traceback

I want to parse some data using Python and do further calculations. I have provided an example of the data i have parsed in the `soup` variable below. I want to convert the 5th value (after comma slicing) from a string into an integer for further processing, but am getting a message saying `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '36.60'`.  Could you help me find what I am doing wrong?

Script:

```
soup = '3-Jan-17,36.61,36.93,36.27,36.60,20196466'
soupy = soup.split('\n')

for line in soupy:
    z = line.split(',')
    yy = z[4]
    zz = int(yy)
```

Message:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '36.60'
```

Comment: `float(yy)` is what you want. Else, `int(float(yy))`

Comment: Doh!  Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zz = int(yy)` should be `zz = float(yy)` 
if you want to convert that to an `int` do this:

`int(float(yy))`

This will [truncate towards `0`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#int)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because the program doesn't recognize the `.` symbol in the string. An integer shouldn't have a decimal part, but your string `"36.60"` looks like having a decimal part.

You can use `int(float(yy))` instead to get `36`.